# Get nth Value of a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, return

[image]Though after writing code and examining it so many times i am getting an assertion error. i dunno why. hope you pals can help me.This is the function

```
int GetNth(struct node* head, int index) {
    Node* current = head;
    int count = 0; // the index of the node we're currently looking at
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == index) 
            return(current->data);
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    assert(0);  
    // if we get to this line, the caller was asking
    // for a non-existent element so we assert fail.
}
```

this is the error i get.

```
GetNth: Assertion `0' failed.Aborted (core dumped)
```

1. My doubt is that if there is a hit with the position whose value is expected, why would Assertion test happen? As there is already a return statement of the while loop which exits the function.
2. If i comment that assertion test and if there is a hit/miss with position whose value is expected, it returns me 0 every time instead of value/null

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you calling the function? What's the values of the arguments? How many nodes are in the list?

Comment: Please post a the real code. Your braces don't match in the example you posted.

Comment: The function itself seems okay, please check the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: Is this perhaps an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)? What value are you passing to get the first value in the list?

Comment: The short or do not yet have list

Comment: hey guys i just posted my output with assert being commented

Comment: Nit-pick: `return` is not a function.

Comment: How do you fill the list? Is it done in a function? how do you pass the head?

Comment: add some trace to check how often you're going round the loop. If you comment out the assert, you'll get whatever the compiler feels like giving you as a result.

Comment: Why do you abort the program(with assert) if you don't find the item, if I would search for the index of 1 in set { -2,4,-5 } I would either return -1, to indicate that index wasn't found or NULL if the function would return a pointer.

Comment: This could be an error in building your list. You might want to post the function add_node() or whatever you call it.

Comment: Sorry pals! My pointer->next was pointing to NULL. And therefore the Segmentation fault and therefore the error. Sorry for wasting your time. I feel so guilty about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debug code like this with good old fashion printf's

```
int GetNth(struct node* head, int index) {
Node* current = head;
int count = 0; // the index of the node we're currently looking at
if ( index < 0 ) {
    printf( "invalid -ve index passes\n" );
    assert(0);
}
printf( "starting ptr %p\n", current );
while (current != NULL) {
    printf( "checking value %d against %d for ptr %p", count, index, current );
    if (count == index) {
        printf( "found\n" );
        return(current->data);
    }
    count++;
    current = current->next;
}
printf( "not found\n" );
assert(0);  
// if we get to this line, the caller was asking
// for a non-existent element so we assert fail.
}
```

Run it and see what you get out. If needed change the printf for fprintf( stderr.

Comment: The Error was, the pointer which my GetNth got as a parameter was pointing to Null. Which was My bad. And thanks for the time and effort to make my code right. Your debugging made my work easy. Thanks :)

Comment: Would this function work if  ```data``` were many? For example, my data are in a struct: rollnumber, source and destination.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some input/output issues, your code looks correct, I think the problem is that the list you are passing in is either NULL, or it doesn't have enough items. And so you hit the assertion failure.

Output issue - assert(0) is not a good way to return an error to a caller of a function. C language provides no way for a caller function to detect the assertion failure. So your process will crash.

Also it is likely that the reason someone is calling your API is they don't know whether the item is in the list or not, so crashing the process is not a good design from that POV.

Input issue - you don't validate the input argument is positive. Or restrict it to being unsigned.

Comment: as you said, i using a reference pointer to head instead of the head pointer. so what happened was,I used the reference pointer to traverse from head till the last node in the list since I had to print all the values in the list. then i used the same pointer(which's next was pointing to NULL)  as a parameter in the GetNth function.And therefore the segmentation fault. Which was sadly the silliest mistake!