# How can I keep a variable from the first element in the list?

Tags: c, list, arraylist, struct

My code below puts in a list informations about packets (represented by roll number, source, destination, and generation time in a struct) from text files. I have an insert function, a remove function, and an output/display function for the lists. Each text file has its own list, for example, text file 1 has link[1] as a list, etc. The packets enter the list and under some conditions, only one list at a time can remove the first packet that has entered the list.

My **problem** is that every time a list removes the first packet I want to calculate `Time-gentime`, *Time* is a variable that increases by 1.0 in a loop, and *gentime* is the generation time from each packet. So how can I find every time the gentime from the first packet in a list?

I thought about a search function that will search (maybe by rollnumber) the whole list in order to find the first one before the packet is removed?

My code is below, do not hesitate to ask about definitions or whatever is needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 105

typedef struct Node {
    int rollnumber, src, dst;
    double gentime;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void
insert_end(Node **head, int rollnumber, int src, int dst, double gentime)
{
    struct Node *new_node = NULL;
    struct Node *last = NULL;

    new_node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to insert element. Out of memory");
        return;
    }

    new_node->rollnumber = rollnumber;
    new_node->src = src;
    new_node->dst = dst;
    new_node->gentime = gentime;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    last = *head;
    while (last->next)
        last = last->next;
    last->next = new_node;
}

void
output(Node *head)
{
    for (Node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        // printf("%d ", current->data);
        printf("Roll Number:%2d\t", current->rollnumber);
        printf("src:%2d\t", current->src);
        printf("dest:%2d\t", current->dst);
        printf("gentime:%0.1f\n", current->gentime);
    }
}

void
display(Node **set, int i)
{
    output(set[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int
remove_node_in_list(Node **set, size_t pos)
{
    int success = set[pos] != NULL;

    if (success) {
        Node *tmp = set[pos];

        set[pos] = set[pos]->next;
        free(tmp);
    }

    return success;
}

#define N   10

int
main(void)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    int src, dst;
    int rollnumber;
    double gentime;
    int stations = 0;
    Node *link[N] = { 0 };
    int i = 1;
    static unsigned long pos[] = { 0 };
    FILE *file;
    char filename_format[] = "fptg_%d.txt";
    char filename[sizeof(filename_format) + 4];
    bool intention[10];
    double Time = 12.0;
    int lower = 0, upper = 9, count = 1;

    srand(time(0));
    int num;
    int k = 1;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    // the time units checking them per one like: 0-1,1-2 etc..
    for (Time = 1.0; Time < 50.0; Time = Time + 1.0) {
        // because I have 10 text files
        while(i<10) {
                //file opened, put the elements in a list of structs
                if (Time < gentime && gentime < Time + 1.0) {
                    pos[i] = ftell(file);
                    insert_end(&link[i], 0, 1, 2, 3.4);
                    insert_end(&link[i+1], 5, 6, 7, 8.9);
                    insert_end(&link[i+1], 5, 6, 7, 8.9);
                    insert_end(&link[i+1], 0, 1, 4, 3.4); 
                    printf("Time=%0.1f\n", Time);
                    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                        int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;                        
                        printf("Random number:%d\n", num);
                        if (num == 1 || num == 6 || num == 8) {
                            intention[i] = true;                             
                            stations++;
                        }
                        else {
                            intention[i] = false;
                            //do something
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (stations == 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            printf("intention[%d]=%d\n", i, intention[i]);
            if (intention[i] == true) {
                printf("link[%d]:\n", i);
                display(link, i);
                printf("i=%d\n", I);
                //here before removing I want to calculate Time-gentime(gentime of the first that is going to be removed
                remove_node_in_list(link, i);
                printf("NEW:\n");
                display(link, i);
            }
        }
    }
    stations = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I found the below function:

```
int GetNth(struct Node* head, int index) {
Node* current = head;
int count = 0; // the index of the node we're currently looking at
if ( index < 0 ) {
    printf( "invalid -ve index passes\n" );
    assert(0);
}
printf( "starting ptr %p\n", current );
while (current != NULL) {
    printf( "checking value %d against %d for ptr %p", count, index, current );
    if (count == index) {
        printf( "found\n" );
        return(current->rollnumber);
    }
    count++;
    current = current->next;
}
printf( "not found\n" );
assert(0);  
// if we get to this line, the caller was asking
// for a non-existent element so we assert fail.
}
```

but when I tried it in my program as:

```
printf("Element at index 3 is %d", GetNth(head, 1));
```

it shows the error:

```
assertion "0" failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your code is fairly big and your question is not fully clear. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Simplify your program as far as possible and provide everything what is needed to build and run it and to reproduce the problem. Make clear what part of the code corresponds to your question.

Comment: @Bodo I do not know what to delete in order to make it more minimal, I think that the above are needed in order to be reproducible.

Comment: When I run your program, the output is several lines `FPTG_1.txt` followed by two empty lines each. Is this the expected behavior? I'm one who tries to help, and when I think that the information in your question is not sufficient, then I cannot help. One way to minimize the program is to separate data input from the processing. Assuming the problem is in the processing, I suggest to remove the part that tries to read files and replace this with hard-coded input data.

Comment: Should I put my text files too? And what do you mean by hard-coded input data?

Comment: @Bodo I just edited and I tried to delete some things that were not the problem and not so useful for it.

Comment: Can you run the code shown in the question and reproduce the problem without any additional files? (I did not try the modified code.) With hard-coded data I mean that you should remove the part that is reading input files and add code that contains the data embedded in the source code., e.g. something like `insert_end(&link[i], 0, 1, 2, 3.4); i++; insert_end(&link[i], 5, 6, 7, 8.9);` etc.

Comment: @Bodo I tried what you asked for, hope it is right.

Comment: I get warnings and errors when I try to build your program, and I got the impression that you did not fully understand my comment about hard-coded data. Please fix your program and make sure you can reproduce the problem with exactly the shown code. The code should create a few example lists and remove a node. I think your function `remove_node_in_list` is wrong. You cannot use a list with an array index.

Comment: The way how the function `GetNth` uses `assert` is bad. (Where did you *find* this function? In the solution of a classmate?) `index < 0` could be avoided with an unsigned type. If you really want to handle an index after the last element as a programming error you should better use a meaningful condition e.g. `assert(index < count)`. Show all output before `assertion "0" failed`. The `printf`s show the relevant information. The index 3 in the text does not match the function argument 1 in `printf("Element at index 3 is %d", GetNth(head, 1));`. BTW: In C, an array index starts with 0 not 1.

Comment: I found the function in another answer here. Although, I do not get your point, thank you for your time.

Comment: Then, please add a link to the answer. (Use the gray `share` below the answer.) To find the problems in your code, please [edit] your question and show the output before `assertion "0" failed`. If it is `not found`, then probably your list doesn't contain an element with index 1 (which is the 2nd element, the first one would have index 0). If you pass `head` from `main` , then you have no elements at all because it is initialized as `NULL` and never modified.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20497544/14631494)

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.** The link alone does not help much. If you dont answer all questions and don't improve your question it is difficult to help. I suggest to run your code in a debugger and check what happens with the variables and your lists while you execute it step-by-step.